# Проблема с dropdown-menu bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

Верстаю форму с применением dropdown-menu. Возникла проблема с отображением подпунктов dropdown-menu (prijs, type, slpk) - они просто не открываются...

Вот сам [проект](http://bot.immo/)

А вот  [[image: скрин]] как должен работать один из подпунктов:

Не могу найти ошибку. Помогите кто может, наведите на правильную мысль. Благодарю.

Comment: Может как здесь ? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns  просто вложите ещё один ul / li  Или вот http://jsfiddle.net/faaLU/2/

Comment: куда именно вложить, ведь все верстал по шаблону...

Comment: Этот "ру стак овер флоу" - выглядит хуже песочницы.
У все все работает, а кому то лень читать документацию и давайте это запостим, и все мельком проглядывая будут думать, что косяк в bootstrap`е.

Comment: косяк обнаружился сам по-себе, data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"